# typescript instanceof my class evaluated as any

Tags: typescript

I have a strange problem and it's clear that my error is about understanding something on instantiating class in Typescript.
In My code I've write it

```
let res:Array<MyClass>=[];
    ......    
console.log(res[0] instanceof MyClass)
```

the expression in console.log() return me a false value, why?

And second question, is it possible to do something like

```
res instanceof Array<MyClass>
```

?

## Update

I have even try to check the type in this way

```
typeof res[0]==="MyClass"
```

still same problem, always get false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happens in case of empty array:

```
class MyClass {

}

let res: Array<MyClass> = [];

console.log(res[0]);
console.log(res[0] instanceof MyClass); // false because res is empty and res[0] is undefined

res.push(new MyClass());

console.log(res[0]);
console.log(res[0] instanceof MyClass); // true
```

I've created corresponding [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ze1sopmh/1/).

Comment: I've used your solution, but partially, I've needed to use a constructor too.